# Why wyciwyg redirect when I try to pass parameter with values in Joomla

Tags: redirect, pagination, joomla2.5

When I try to pass variable with values like ?page=1 it redirected with `http://wyciwyg://{number}`

Comment: Without codes, how can we help ?

Comment: I am just testing my module with custom pagination in Joomla2.5 and passing '?page=1' but it redirecting with 'http://wyciwyg://[number]/URL' I have created only testing module and called it in article with '{loadpostion pagination}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple,

You can remove script tag from prohibited elements list in TinyMCE plugin basic options.

Answer (score 2):

Finally got the clue, removed `<script>` tag from custom module and it is solved. :)